# Применить стиль к динамически созданному элементу java

Tags: java, android-studio

Первый раз пробую писать приложение для андроид.
Добавил кнопку в визуальном редакторе, создал стиль. Далее удалил кнопку и пытаюсь добавить ее динамически с этим стилем.

```
     ll = (LinearLayout) ((Activity) this.context).findViewById(R.id.objects);
     Context themedContext = new ContextThemeWrapper(this.context, R.style.LeftButtonEvents_Enabled);
     Button btnNew = new Button(themedContext);
     btnNew.setText("T");
     ll.addView(btnNew);
```

А вот так определил стили:

```
 <style name="LeftButtonEvents">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">40dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:elevation">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">#000000</item>
</style>
<style name="LeftButtonEvents.Enabled">
    <item name="android:background">#4682B4</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#fff00f</item>
</style>
<style name="LeftButtonEvents.Disabled">
    <item name="android:background">#191970</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#fff00f</item>
</style>
```

Все применяется, кроме background...
При попытке применить btnNew.setBackgroundColor(R.color.eventButtonEnabled);
теряется margin

Answer (score 0):

Не понял почему не применялся background и исчезал margin при изменении цвета, сделал так:

`LinearLayout.LayoutParams lParam1;

btnNew.setBackgroundResource(R.color.eventButton);
lParam1 = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btnNew.getLayoutParams();
lParam1.setMargins(5,5,5,5);`

работает